# Replace word starting with @ symbol with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, parsing, replace, html-parsing

I am trying to create a link when someone writes @NameHere, but with my actual code it doesn't work. The code does not read the $1 as the word placed after the @. It does if I place a whitespace after the code (like `/^@(.*?)/ig` ), but then it will read punctuations marks as part of the mentioned name. If left without the white space (`/^@(.*?)/ig`), it won't read the word.

I've been trying to fix but don't know how.

https://jsfiddle.net/ElenaMcDowell/pebjtwrz/79/

```
<div class="previewDocument-box">
    <h1>Preview</h1>
    <div class="previewDocument-text"></div>
</div>
<textarea id="ECEditor" class="editor-textarea" style="height: 200px;" name="editor-text"></textarea>

$('#ECEditor').on('input', function() {
     var text = $(this).val();
     var bb =  [
            /\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/ig,
        /^@(.*?)/ig
        
    ];
    
    var bb_html = [
            '<strong>$1</strong>',
        '<a class="MLPrev" href="profile?id=$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>&nbsp;'
    ];
 
    for (var i =0;i<bb.length;i++) {
      text = text.replace(bb[i], bb_html[i]);
    }
     $('.previewDocument-text').html(text);
  });
```

Comment: `.*?` matches 0 or more characters, as little as possible. Of course it’ll match nothing if you don’t provide a delimiter after it, e.g. `(?:\s|$)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you actually need is the following:

```
/@(\w+)(\b)/g
```

This will match a sequence of "word" characters, followed by a "word boundary" (essentially a non-word character such as a space or punctuation, or the end of the line).

The use of `i` is redundant, so I've removed it from the match.

Note we also *don't* anchor the match to the start of the line, since that would not work if the tag appears mid-text.

Your replacement would then become:

```
'<a class="MLPrev" href="profile?id=$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>$2'
```

(which is the same, except that instead of inserting a non-breaking space, we insert whatever character followed the tag - whether its a space or punctuation, or other "non-word" character).

Here is a working snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="previewDocument-box">
    <h1>Preview</h1>
    <div class="previewDocument-text"></div>
  </div>

  <textarea id="ECEditor" class="editor-textarea" style="height: 200px;" name="editor-text"></textarea>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#ECEditor').on('input', function() {
      let text = $(this).val();
      const bb = [
        /\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/g,
        /@(\w+)(\b)/g
      ];

      const bb_html = [
        '<strong>$1</strong>',
        '<a class="MLPrev" href="profile?id=$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>$2'
      ];

      for (let i = 0; i < bb.length; i++) {
        text = text.replace(bb[i], bb_html[i]);
      }
      $('.previewDocument-text').html(text);
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, this approach ensures that the tag is hyperlinked *while typing*, rather than forcing the user to insert something afterwards (such as a space or punctuation). Therefore, it would also work if the tag appeared at the end of the line.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and for taking the time to explain it in an easy way for me to understand, I really appreciate it!